# How can I ungroup chart components in PowerPoint 2007 (charts imported from Excel)?

Tags: charts, ms-office, powerpoint

Now this is being discussed a lot online and there seems to be no concrete answer as yet.

In Powerpoint 2007, when I import a graph created in excel. (I have tried all types of paste options), I cannot ungroup the graph components beyond a certain level.

For example, I can ungroup the bars from the axes, but I cannot ungroup the bars individually in a bar chart. This was possible in Office 2003.

There are a lot of work arounds suggested like creating the graph in Powerpoint etc. Is there an official Microsoft response on this? 
here:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3770#overview

In SP1 update for Office 2007, the description of changes mentions a similar fix:
*"When you try to manually ungroup an imported picture through the user interface of PowerPoint 2007, you may receive the following informational message: 
This is an imported picture, not a group. Do you want to convert it to a Microsoft Office drawing object? 
If you click Yes, the picture will be converted to a drawing object. 
When you try to programmatically ungroup the imported picture by selecting the picture and using the ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Ungroup method in the Visual Basic Editor, you may receive the error message: 
Run-time error '-2147024891 (80070005)': This member can only be accesses for a group. "*

Has anyone successfully fixed this in Office 2007?

Answer (score 1):

To ungroup a 2007/2010 chart (manually or programmatically) you have to copy it, paste special as WMF or EMF, then delete the original chart and ungroup the EMF/WMF picture.

The chart may use a type of shape (or perhaps it's a variant on the polygon shape) that has no user interface (the axes + tick marks, for example) so you can't edit it manually or ungroup it any further.  I don't know of any way around that, unless it might possibly be digging into the XML.

Comment: Thank Steve. My problem is that I need to ungroup further. For example for a bar chart, 2007 ppt considers all bars together as one shape, and doesnt allow further ungroup to separate rectangles!

Comment: Rats. First reply got eaten.  The bars are another example of these weird uneditable shapes.  Can't ungroup, can't edit points.  I had a look though, and it turns out you *can* get at them via the XML.  I added a chart, ungrouped it a few times, deleted all but the bars, then saved and looked at the XML for the slide.  The shape is defined by loads of lineto commands; you can edit these and see the result when you open in PPT again.  Other than that ... don't know of any other fix.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution I found is to color each bar in different color in the excell.
After you paste it (as metafile) into powerpoint , it is easy to ungroup and move or chgane each bar.